# Binomial distribution $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Which is the value of

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{x=0}^{x=n/2} \varepsilon^{2x}(1-\varepsilon)^{n-2x} \frac{n!}{(2x)!(n-(2x))!}
$$

i.e the limit of the Binomial distribution summed over all even values of an also even $n$ ($0, 2, 4,\ldots$)? I suppose that it should give $1/2$. Can someone tell me if it is true?

Comment: Yes. You can even compute the value before the limit:$$\frac{1+(1-2\epsilon)^n}{2}.$$ I am also assuming, based on your reference to binomial distribution, that the exponent of $1-\epsilon$ is in fact $n-2x$.

Comment: Thank you @SangchulLee. The value $\frac{1+(1-2\epsilon)^{n}}{2}$, how is it proven? (Only approximately).
Yes of course, it was a typo now corrected.

Comment: The general trick for this kind of problem is that you use sifting property of sums of powers of roots of the unity (so many use of 'of's!). For instance, $$(a+b)^n + (a-b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}(b^k + (-b)^k), $$ and the odd-th terms cancel out while even-th terms double up, and in this way it sifts up only even-th terms. So $$\frac{(a+b)^n + (a-b)^n}{2} = \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\text{ even}}}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}b^k.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee haha perfect! Very useful. Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, taking the even part of $(1+x)^n$ using the Binomial Theorem:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_k\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}
&=\frac12\left[\sum_k\binom{n}{k}x^k+\sum_k\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k\right]\\[6pt]
&=\frac12\left[(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n\right]
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}\varepsilon^{2k}(1-\varepsilon)^{n-2k}
&=(1-\varepsilon)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}\left(\frac\varepsilon{1-\varepsilon}\right)^{2k}\\
&=\frac12(1-\varepsilon)^n\left[\left(1+\frac\varepsilon{1-\varepsilon}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac\varepsilon{1-\varepsilon}\right)^n\right]\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\left[1+(1-2\varepsilon)^n\right]
\end{align}
$$
So, for $0\lt\varepsilon\lt1$, we get the limit of $\frac12$. Note that this excludes $\varepsilon=0$ and $\varepsilon=1$.